# Assign methods from class in imported module to current namespace

Tags: python

I would like assign methods (more at once) from class in imported module to current namespace and I would like to do the "assign process" not in the "current" namespace but from the imported module. How can I do that?

This file is imported from another one:

```
# File mylib.py

class MyLib():
    def hello1(self, text):
        print('hello1: %s' % text)

    def goodbye1(self, text):
        print('goodbye1: %s' % text)

    def hello2(self, text):
        print('hello2: %s' % text)

    def goodbye2(self, text):
        print('goodbye2: %s' % text)

    def assign1(self):
        pass
        # This should assign self.hello1() and self.goodbye1()
        # to "parent" namespace as hello() and goodbye()

    def assign2(self):
        pass
        # Similar behaviour to self.assign1()
```

This file is the "main" one.

```
# File myscript.py

import mylib

l = mylib.MyLib()
l.assign1()

# After this I would like to have MyLib.hello1() assigned to hello()
# and MyLib.goodbye1() to goodbye()

hello('hi')
goodbye('see you')

l.assign2()
# After this I would like to have MyLib.hello2() assigned to hello()
# and MyLib.goodbye2() to goodbye()

hello('hi')
goodbye('see you')
```

So far I tried `globals()` with no success and found that `__builtins__` might work but seemed not the right way because of polluting `__builtins__` namespace with content that does not belong there.

What I do NOT want:

```
# In the "current" namespace
hello = l.hello1
goodbye = l.goodbye1

# Instead I want

l.assign1()
# Now hello() and goodbye() are mapped to l.hello1() and l.goodbye1()
# "automatically" - the assign process was done in l.assign1(),
# not here in the "current" namespace.
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `assign1` take the namespace you want assigned

```
    def assign1(self, namespace):
        namespace['hello'] = self.hello1
        namespace['goodbye'] = self.goodbye1
```

Now the caller would

```
import mylib
l = mylib.MyLib()
l.assign1(globals())
```

Comment: Thanks everybody who posted an answer. This one solved my problem. I modified that a bit - I pass the globals() to MyLib.__init__() so I don't have to pass it to assign1() or assign2()

Answer (score 0):

You can put variables into the *module's global namespace* with `globals()`. Is this sufficient...?

File: submodule.py

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, baz="Hi!"):
        self.baz = baz

    def foo(self):
        print("foo %s" % self.baz)

    def assign(self):
        globals()["foo"] = self.foo
```

main script:

```
import submodule

bar = submodule.Bar()
bar2 = submodule.Bar("Bye!")

bar.assign()
submodule.foo()

bar2.assign()
submodule.foo()
```

output:

```
foo Hi!
foo Bye!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to restructure your code so you don't have to do that, perhaps like this:

```
# File mylib.py

class MyLib():
    #...

    def assign1(self):
        return hello1, goodbye1

    #likewise for assign2
```

And for the main script...

```
# File myscript.py

import mylib

l = mylib.MyLib()
hello, goodbye = l.assign1()
```

---

If you *really* want to change what's in the parent namespace, then perhaps one way to do this is as follows:

```
# File mylib.py

class MyLib():
    def __init__(self, funcs): #funcs should be a list
        self.funcs = funcs

    #...

    def assign1(self):
        # This should assign self.hello1() and self.goodbye1()
        # to "parent" namespace as hello() and goodbye()

        self.funcs[0].__code__ = self.hello1.__code__
        self.funcs[1].__code__ = self.goodbye1.__code__

    #likewise for assign2
```

And for the main script...

```
# File myscript.py

import mylib

hello = lambda s:s
goodbye = lambda s:s

l = mylib.MyLib([hello, goodbye])
l.assign1()
```

However, I'd like to say that this strikes me as rather..."dirty". Like, this isn't really very clean or Pythonic. For future/bigger programs, use the first way.